# Is it possible to access google drive realtime api from a Firefox extension

Tags: google-drive-realtime-api

I know GDRA is available for Chrome extensions, but I need it for Firefox. If I choose the "Web" option I need to provide an OAuth return address, which I don't have of course. Is there a way around this, or can I use the Chrome version of GDRA with Firefox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can get an OAuth token, you can use the Realtime API. I'm not familiar with the Firefox extension API, but you might take a look at this OAuth implementation which is designed to be used in Firefox extensions:

https://github.com/mozilla/oauthorizer